# How to create a Keras layer to do a 4D convolutions (Conv4D)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

It seems that `tf.nn.convolution` should be able to do 4D convolutions, but I haven't been able to succeed in creating a Keras layer to use this function.

I have tried using Keras `Lambda` layer to wrap the `tf.nn.convolution` function but maybe somebody else has a better idea?

I want to exploit the higher-dimensional structure of my data, so reshaping might not be able to capture the nature of my dataset.

Answer (score 8):

Super cool question.

This needs a custom layer (with trainable parameters).
The following accepts any number of dimensions, you control that via `kernel_size`.

```
class Conv(Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, padding='VALID', **kwargs):
        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size #must be a tuple!!!!
        self.padding=padding

        super(Conv, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    #using channels last!!!
    def build(self, input_shape):
        spatialDims = len(self.kernel_size)
        allDims = len(input_shape)
        assert allDims == spatialDims + 2 #spatial dimensions + batch size + channels

        kernelShape = self.kernel_size + (input_shape[-1], self.filters)
            #(spatial1, spatial2,...., spatialN, input_channels, output_channels)

        biasShape = tuple(1 for _ in range(allDims-1)) + (self.filters,)


        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                      shape=kernelShape
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        self.bias = self.add_weight(name='bias', 
                                    shape = biasShape, 
                                    initializer='zeros',
                                    trainable=True)
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs):
        results = tf.nn.convolution(inputs, self.kernel, padding=self.padding)
        return results + self.bias

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape)
        sizes = input_shape[1:-1]

        if self.padding='VALID' or self.padding='valid':
            sizes = [s - kSize + 1 for s, kSize in zip(sizes, self.kernel_size)]

        return input_shape[:1] + sizes + (self.filters,)
```

Comment: Unfortuantely I asked this question at the onset the coronavirus craziness and taking care of a young one while trying to work isn't easy so I haven't been able to test your solution (that project has lower priority at the moment), but I am immensely grateful for your answer. I just didn't want to let more time pass without saying thanks. THANKS!

Comment: Great answer. I will also give it a try. Can you please make an example how to use it with 4D data? Can dropout and batch normalization just used as usual or do they also have to be reimplemented?

Comment: @machinery, kernel size must be 4D. Example: `kernel_size = (k1, k2, k3, k4)`. Your data, naturally, will have to be 6D (as with any keras convolution, 1 extra for samples, 1 extra for channels). `data_shape = (samples, d1, d2, d3, d4, channels)`.   The model's `input_shape`, which usually ignores the batch size must be 5D (without samples) or 6D (with samples): `input_shape = (d1_or_None, d2_or_None, d3_or_None, d4_or_None, channels)`

Comment: @machinery, you can use regular dropout and batch normalization as usual. For `SpatialDropout`, it must be reimplemented. You can look at the codes for `SpatialDropout2D` and `3D` and you can easily deduce how to extend it to more Ds. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/5a7a789ee9766b6a594bd4be8b9edb34e71d6500/keras/layers/core.py

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for TF 2.3, where tf.nn.convolution only handles Conv1D, Conv2D, or Conv3D. (`num_spatial_dims (input.shape.ndims - num_batch_dims - 1) must be one of 1, 2 or 3`)

Comment: @Dejvovo Does it work in TF 2.2? I'm willing to use an older version to get this feature.

Comment: @David, how many dimensions do you need? It's not very hard to workaround to 4, but it gets more and more complicated for higher dimensions.

Comment: @Moller I was hoping for arbitrarily many, and testing out where I reached a limit for acceptable training times. But at a minimum, I am aiming for at least 6. The size of my dimensions is very tiny, so I don't think performance will be too bad at that number.

Answer (score 6):

You are right there is not much support for Tensorflow Conv4D right now.
I coded this repo (https://github.com/Vincentx15/Conv4D) that addresses that and includes flexible striding and padding.

It adds a lightweight dependency on Sonnet to use advanced padding, but this should blend in tensorflow code seamlessly.

Best :)

Comment: I also included a Conv4D in Jax :)